# Enable button when options are changed after data is received from API vue.js without lodash

Tags: vue.js

I`m trying to make a button enable after I change values of select and after the data is received from API. I have colors:[] array in data that get populated after I search something. I tried to do something with watch but don`t get any positive results. I cloned the empty array than after, watch It for  the new values but the watch is triggered just one time, when I search that value. Any Idea how I can make the watch track all the changes that are made ? I will attach the code below.Thanks and sorry If I wasn`t too explicit.
P.S I used deep:true, but the same results.

```
      computed: {
    clonedItems(){
      return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.options))
    },
  },
  watch: {
    clonedItems: {
      handler: function(newVal, oldVal){
        console.log('new', newVal);
        console.log('old', oldVal);
        if ( newVal === oldVal ){
          this.isDisabled = false;
      
        } else {
          this.isDisabled = true;
         
        }
      },
    },
    deep: true
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

bind some condition to the attribute `disabled` on the button:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const colors = ref<[] | undefined>(undefined)
</script>

<template>
   <button :disabled="colors != undefined"></button>
</template>
```

Comment: The colors = [] receive values from API when I m searching Something in search field, like some default values.I need the save Button to get enabled  when I change these values and yes I bonded the Button with the function. ```:disabled= clonedItems``` thanks for the answer anyway